# Como pegar o valor de uma propriedade usando variável como nome?

Tags: javascript, propriedade

Como fazer ele buscar a propriedade `ABC` ao invés de `A`?   Levando em consideração este código:

```
A = 'ABC';    
alert(LANG.A);
```

Comment: Como assim, explique melhor. E o que é `LANG`?

Comment: @bfavaretto uma árvore de JSON

Comment: `alert(LANG[A]);` - é isto que você quer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `LANG.A` do seu exemplo procura uma propriedade chamada `A` no objeto `LANG`. Já `LANG[A]` procura uma propriedade cujo nome seja o valor da variável `A`, ou seja, `'ABC'` – portanto equivale a `LANG.ABC`. Acredito que você esteja querendo esse segundo caso.

Comment: Nossa me esqueci completamente dos colchetes, Obrigado!