# Como acessar um objeto por uma variável

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

```
  function aliasGen(fname, lname){
  const firstName = {
  A: 'Alpha',
  B: 'Beta',
  C: 'Cache',
  D: 'Data',
  E: 'Energy',
  F: 'Function',
  G: 'Glitch',
  H: 'Half-life',
  I: 'Ice',
  J: 'Java',
  K: 'Keystroke',
  L: 'Logic',
  M: 'Malware',
  N: 'Nagware',
  O: 'OS',
  P: 'Phishing',
  Q: 'Quantum',
  R: 'RAD',
  S: 'Strike',
  T: 'Trojan',
  U: 'Ultraviolet',
  V: 'Vanilla',
  W: 'WiFi',
  X: 'Xerox',
  Y: 'Y',
  Z: 'Zero',
}
const surname = {
  A: 'Analogue',
  B: 'Bomb',
  C: 'Catalyst',
  D: 'Discharge',
  E: 'Electron',
  F: 'Faraday',
  G: 'Gig',
  H: 'Hacker',
  I: 'IP',
  J: 'Jabber',
  K: 'Killer',
  L: 'Lazer',
  M: 'Mike',
  N: 'n00b',
  O: 'Overclock',
  P: 'Payload',
  Q: 'Quark',
  R: 'Roy',
  S: 'Spy',
  T: 'T-Rex',
  U: 'Unit',
  V: 'Virus',
  W: 'Worm',
  X: 'X',
  Y: 'Yob',
  Z: 'Zombie',
}
  fname = fname.split('')
  lname = lname.split('')
  fname = fname[0]
  lname = lname[0]
  let string = ''
  string+=firstName.fname
  return firstName.fname
}
```

Onde `fname` é a primeira letra do nome da pessoa e eu Eu quero por exemplo chamar Guilherme era pra mostrar Glitch mas retorna `undefined`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como pegar o valor de uma propriedade usando variável como nome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67863/como-pegar-o-valor-de-uma-propriedade-usando-vari%c3%a1vel-como-nome)

Comment: E também: [O que são nomes computados (desestruturação "dinâmica") em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430322/100416)

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue acessar o valor de um objeto pela sua chave

```
obj = {
 A: "Goku"
}
```

para acessar goku, você acessar assim:

```
obj.A ou obj['A']
```

Então para ajeitar seu código apenas mude essa parte:

```
  string+=firstName.fname
```

por essa:

```
 string+=firstName[fname]
```

```js
function aliasGen(fname, lname){
  const firstName = {
    A: 'Alpha',
    B: 'Beta',
    C: 'Cache',
    D: 'Data',
    E: 'Energy',
    F: 'Function',
    G: 'Glitch',
    H: 'Half-life',
    I: 'Ice',
    J: 'Java',
    K: 'Keystroke',
    L: 'Logic',
    M: 'Malware',
    N: 'Nagware',
    O: 'OS',
    P: 'Phishing',
    Q: 'Quantum',
    R: 'RAD',
    S: 'Strike',
    T: 'Trojan',
    U: 'Ultraviolet',
    V: 'Vanilla',
    W: 'WiFi',
    X: 'Xerox',
    Y: 'Y',
    Z: 'Zero',
  }
    const surname = {
    A: 'Analogue',
    B: 'Bomb',
    C: 'Catalyst',
    D: 'Discharge',
    E: 'Electron',
    F: 'Faraday',
    G: 'Gig',
    H: 'Hacker',
    I: 'IP',
    J: 'Jabber',
    K: 'Killer',
    L: 'Lazer',
    M: 'Mike',
    N: 'n00b',
    O: 'Overclock',
    P: 'Payload',
    Q: 'Quark',
    R: 'Roy',
    S: 'Spy',
    T: 'T-Rex',
    U: 'Unit',
    V: 'Virus',
    W: 'Worm',
    X: 'X',
    Y: 'Yob',
    Z: 'Zombie',
  }
 
  return firstName[fname] + ' ' + surname[lname]
}

console.log(aliasGen("G", "M"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Se a questão é digitar guilherme no fname e retornar o Glitch, eu faria algo assim:

```
const spliting = fname.split(‘’);

const find = firstName[spliting[0]];

console.log(find)
```